# how to send private variable function1 to function2 without using session variable laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm want to send variable $blog to function images

```php
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
{
    $blog = auth()->user()->blog()->create([
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
    ]);
    // ส่งค่าตัวแปรไปยังฟังก์ชั่น images
    images($blog);
    session(['blogId' => $blog->id]);
    return response()->json(['status'=>"success"]);
}

public function images(Request $request)
{
    dd($blog);
    $blogId = session('blogId');
}
```

Comment: In images function, you should initiate a blog variable. Instead of request parameter, you should give $blog parameter

Comment: create a private variable into class, and to store values into that use, `$this->blog= value` and use in another function `$this->blog`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is accept it as a function parameter.

```php
public function images($blog)
{
    dd($blog);
}
```

And call it in your function.

```
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
{
    $blog = auth()->user()->blog()->create([
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
    ]);
    // ส่งค่าตัวแปรไปยังฟังก์ชั่น images

    $this->images($blog); // don't forget $this

    session(['blogId' => $blog->id]);
    return response()->json(['status'=>"success"]);
}
```